# How to stash unmerged code in git?

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I did a git pull and found that one of my files needs to be merged.

I don't really want to merge that file right now - I have another branch that I need to work on, and I will get back to this branch later to resolve the merge.

What is the best course of action for me to "undo" this pull? Or how can I hold off on this merge until I'm ready to deal with it? What do I need to do to be able to change branches, but then return to this unmerged state in my code?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a good example of why I reckon doing a fetch instead of a pull is a good idea.

What you can do is simply reset your branch to it's previous state..

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

or if you are already in the middle of the merge (resolving conflicts), just abort it..

```
git merge --abort
```

finish your changes and then...

```
git fetch
...have a look at what's changed 
git merge origin/branch
```

An easy way to see what has changed is to do

```
git cherry branch origin/branch -v --abbrev=6
```

That will give you a list of commits that are in the origin branch but not in your branch...if you need the details of what changed in that commit then

```
git show commit --name-status
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to blow away changes on a current HEAD, `git reset --hard` is your ticket.
This should allow you to swap branches and return to this one and redo this merge at a later date.

If you are rebasing, `git rebase --abort` will cancel the operation as well.

Answer (score 1):

`git stash` was complaining about unmerged changes after I did a `git stash pop` that resulted in merge conflicts, but I had already resolved them manually.

Doing `git add .` and then `git stash` worked great.

Comment: This adds all files that were not intended to be added to commit.